# call function after slidetoggle complete

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#newrecord tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#newrecord tr:not(.odd)").find("li").hide();
    $("#newrecord tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#newrecord tr:first-child").show();

    $("#newrecord tr.odd").click(function () {
        $("#newrecord tr:not(.odd)").show();
        $(this).next("tr").find("li").slideToggle("slow","swing");
    });
});
```

The following first hides all the even rows and when we click on the odd row it displays the even row and the slides down the li content of each row. I need help with when I click again the li tag slides up as I want it, but it should also hide the row. that is should call hide function on the row after slide up.

Comment: What would we _poor_ programmers do without jQuery? _(use zepto?)_

Comment: By just taking a look at the official jQuery documentation you would find your answer http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#newrecord tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#newrecord tr:not(.odd)").find("li").hide();
    $("#newrecord tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#newrecord tr:first-child").show();

    $("#newrecord tr.odd").click(function () {
        $("#newrecord tr:not(.odd)").show();
        $(this).next("tr").find("li").slideToggle("slow","swing", function(){
            //What to do on toggle compelte...
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: but the function is called every when it slides down, I want the function to be called only when it slides up

Comment: Excellent answer; exactly what I needed. One minor thing to add is the "swing" is default & is probably optional.

Comment: @Hrishikesh Sardar add and remove a class like "is_open" and use slideDown(your function here()) and slideUp() based on if it has the class. Use it the same way as slideToggle.

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar, I realise this is an old question, but you can test if the slide was up and the content is now closed by including a test like `if($(this).is(":hidden")) {...`

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following code

```
$(this).next("tr").find("li").slideToggle("slow","swing", function(){
    // here you code after toggle complete
});
```

Comment: but the function is called every when it slides down, I want the function to be called only when it slides up

Answer (score 1):

Lwyrn is correct, adding the third parameter to the slideToggle call will do it. For more control yet you can pass a plain object with all of the options you'd like as a parameter ( eg. .slideToggle( options )). You can read more about what those options can do at : http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/#slideToggle-options

I find it useful to pass the object when I don't want the animation to queue (if a user clicks 50 times really fast, the animation will stack and keep toggling for a while -- undesired behavior).

Comment: but the function is called every when it slides down, I want the function to be called only when it slides up

Comment: I see. I think you should split the slideToggle call into the two parts of the animation, slideUp and slideDown. Then in an if statement determine which animation function to use depending on the truth of css('visibility') === 'hidden'. Then you can pass a callback function to slideDown just as before. See http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/